# Strikeout doesn't work properly with markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, design, markdown

Strikeout in HTML (using `<s>`...`</s>` or `<del>`...`</del>`) doesn't strike out links to tags as specified in mardown. For example:

```
<s>See [tag:discussion] for some questions that require discussion.</s>
```

is interpreted as

> <s>See [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) for some questions that require discussion.</s>

here. However, on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), the above is rendered as

[image]

This is clearly a bug.

Comment: I guess the CSS style for badge names resets the strike-out setting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I pushed a fix to our dev server. It will be on live after the next production build.